# pwsz string confusion

Tags: c++

I have never posted before so I am sorry if I am not clear. I am trying to use a third party DLL written in c++ on 2005 and all I have is some very poor documentation. I am dynamically linking to the DLL and using the Ordinal value read from Dependency walker to get a pointer to a method in the DLL. Such as (LPFNDDLLZC)  GetProcAddress(hHILCdll, (LPCSTR)15);

My code is written in C++ compiled in Microsoft VS 6.0, I can not turn on the UNICODE defines or I will break existing code.

The documentation for the DLL says all string arguments are pwsz which I believe means pointer to a wide char string null terminated.

I have tried passing in a pointer to an unsigned short, BSTR and various other things and the DLL crashes on the string. I am totally lost as to why, I believe it has to do with my pwsz string construction and I'm lost as to how to fix this. I have read so may articles related but nothing works.

Can anyone help? I can post code if need be.

Thanks.

Comment: Document the LPFNDDLLZC declaration.

Comment: I don't speak Hungarian Notation, so what is "pwsz"?  Also, what is "LPFNDDLLZC"?

Comment: typedef  long (__stdcall * LPFNDDLLZC) (long x, long y, long long z,
                                        long a, long b, long long c,
                                        long d, unsigned short* pwszmsg);  

LPFNDDLLZC is just my pointer name to the method in the DLL. 

I am not up on Hungarian notation either, I thought developers stopped using it long ago. Anyway they tell me here that its a pointer to a wide character string null terminated. 

The DLL came with no header file or .def file so I am going on the small documentation I have for the method signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072) to turn your LPSTR into an LPWSTR which should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone. I did finally get a copy of the DLL source and my problem wasn't my string construction it was the poor documentation. Turns out they are using double pointers, fixes a ton of things!